# Blank page with multiple table select

Tags: sql, mysql

Having these queries, but on running it gives me blank pages. Maybe bacause the $query->result function is not good for "him"? (It's ExpressionEngine)

```
$query = $DB->query("SELECT fr.uri AS smth, ch.uri 
                       FROM exp_static_page_caching_uris AS fr,              
                            exp_static_page_caching_queue AS ch 
                      WHERE fr.uri != ch.uri");         

foreach($query->result as $row) {      
  $DB->query($DB->insert_string('exp_static_page_caching_queue',
                                 array('site_id'   => '1',
                                'uri'              => $row['smth']),
                                TRUE));
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that your query returns the data you want/need?

Comment: I see no error checking in your code. I presume you also have display_errors set to off :-?

Comment: @Ponies: You're right, there is no data returned, my logic failed :) I only want those result from the fr table, where the ch.uri doesn't the same, even if the ch table is empyt.
So i want to duplicate the URI-s into the ch table from fr, if the URI doesn't exists in ch table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$query->result_array()` instead of `$query->result`

Comment: No :( I think result_array is only in EE2